# GridView classes could not be instantiated

Tags: java, android, xml, gridview, shared-libraries

I want to use the GridView layout. my min and max API values are 8 to 17.

I am using android android-support-v13.jar.

I have also included gridlayout_v7 as library into my project from the extras/support/android/v7/  folder of the SDK.

**MY LAYOUT XML**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center"
>
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

**THE ERROR I GET**

The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.

Comment: Simply give <GridView it will work.

Comment: Thanks. just wanted to know if it is possible to add different views like images and button to each cell of the grid through xml.something like what is shown here.... http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/GridLayout-in-Android